# How to disable single product using id in sql?

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql

How can I disable or enable a product using it id in sql or model method. Can some on help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Load your product using it's repository, get repository using DI.
Then do

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$this->_productRepository->save(product);
```

Via DB:

Find `status` attribute_id from `eav_attributes` table using it's code (97 for me)
Then find a combination of your `attribute_id` and `entity_id` inside `catalog_product_entity_int` table, and set desired value.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code :

```
$productId = 12; // Product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$product->setStatus(1); // 1 = enabled and 0 = disabled
$product->save();
```

Thanks